# Json object is empty in success of ajax

Tags: ajax, json, jquery

I'm returning a Json object from controller using objectMapper. But in success it is showing data is empty. Cant find a solution. Pls Help

```
function voteAction(questionId, votedByUserId, action) {
    $.ajax({
        url: '/voteQuestion?questionId=' + questionId + '&votedByUserId=' + votedByUserId + '&action=' + action,
        contentType: 'application/json',
        dataType: 'json',
        async: false,
        success: function response(data) {
            console.info("data in vote action is  :: " + data);
            var votesCount = data.votesCount;
            alert("votes count::" + votesCount);
            var status = data.status;
            console.log(status + " :: is the status");
            if (status == 10) {
                $("#voice-box").fadeIn();
                document.getElementById("statusMessage").innerHTML = "You've already VotedUp for this Question";
                document.getElementById("voice-box").setAttribute("status", "saved");
                setTimeout("hideStatusMessage()", 1950);
            }
            else if (status == -10) {
                $("#voice-box").fadeIn();
                document.getElementById("statusMessage").innerHTML = "You've already VotedDown for this Question";
                document.getElementById("voice-box").setAttribute("status", "saved");
                setTimeout("hideStatusMessage()", 1950);
            }
            else {
                if (status == 10) {
                    $("#voice-box").fadeIn();
                    document.getElementById("statusMessage").innerHTML = "You've successfully Voted for this Question";
                    document.getElementById("voice-box").setAttribute("status", "saved");
                    setTimeout("hideStatusMessage()", 1950);
                }
            }
            $('#questionVotes h3').html(votesCount);
        }
    });
}
```

this is my controller

```
@RequestMapping(value="/voteQuestion",method=RequestMethod.GET)
public @ResponseBody void voteQuestion(@RequestParam("questionId")String id,@RequestParam("votedByUserId")String votedByUserId,@RequestParam("action")String action,HttpServletResponse response) throws JsonProcessingException, IOException, Throwable
{
         response.getWriter().println(objMapper.writeValueAsString(discussionService.updateVotesByQuestionId(id, votedByUserId, action)));
    }
```

And this is my service method.

```
public static Map<String, Integer> updateVotesByQuestionId(String questionId,String votedByUserId, String action)
     {
         int voteCount=0;
         int  status=0;
         System.out.println("action=="+action);
         Map<String,Integer> returnMap=new HashMap <String,Integer>();
         String responseString="";
         Questions question=questionsDAO.getQuestionByQuestionId(Long.parseLong(questionId));
         List<String> votedUpUsersList = question.getVotedUpUserIds();
         List<String> votedDownUsersList = question.getVotedDownUserIds();
         if(action.equals("voteUp")){
         if(votedUpUsersList.contains(votedByUserId))
         {       
              status=10;
         }
         else{

          if(votedDownUsersList.contains(votedByUserId))
          {
           votedDownUsersList.remove(votedByUserId);
           question.setVotedDownUserIds(votedDownUsersList);

          }
         votedUpUsersList.add(votedByUserId);
         question.setVotedUpUserIds(votedUpUsersList);

         responseString=questionsDAO.saveQuestion(question);
         }}
         else if(action.equals("voteDown")){
             if(votedDownUsersList.contains(votedByUserId)){
                  status=-10;

             }
             else
             {

                  if(votedUpUsersList.contains(votedByUserId))
                  {
                   votedUpUsersList.remove(votedByUserId);
                   question.setVotedUpUserIds(votedUpUsersList);

                  }
                 votedDownUsersList.add(votedByUserId);
                 question.setVotedDownUserIds(votedDownUsersList);

                 responseString=questionsDAO.saveQuestion(question);
                 }
         }
         if(responseString == "Success"){
             voteCount= question.getVotedUpUserIds().size()-question.getVotedDownUserIds().size();
             returnMap.put("voteCount",voteCount);
             returnMap.put("status",status);

         }

         return returnMap;

        }
```

Comment: Have you used something like Chrome developer tools network tab to see what the request is actually responding with?

Comment: Well... maybe you are not returning anything from the server. How can we know? [Learn how to **debug** JavaScript](http://www.netmagazine.com/tutorials/javascript-debugging-beginners).

Comment: You need to first make sure that the server is responding with some sort of content. Then you must make sure that the response content type is actually JSON.

Comment: In networks tab its showing {} and on alert it showing [Object object].

Comment: @user2393464 use `alert(JSON.stringify(data))`

Comment: In Chrome, use console.log instead of alert when outputting the data. Then look in the console tab for the output, it will pretty-print the JSON. However, based on your previous comment, it definitely looks lik the problem is on the backend, {} is an empty JS object...

Comment: I tried with returning a string and also alerting JSON.stringify. It again showed {}

Comment: @user2393464 may be `discussionService.updateVotesByQuestionId(id, votedByUserId, action)` returns nothing?

Comment: Im returning a map in serviceMethod llya

Comment: @user2393464 may be your map is empty, debug it

Comment: Hmm You're right ! My map is empty. The responseString is Showing null

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Return your json object as string from method

```
public @ResponseBody String voteQuestion(...)
```

instead of

```
public @ResponseBody void voteQuestion(...)
```

full method

```
@RequestMapping(value="/voteQuestion",method=RequestMethod.GET)
public @ResponseBody String voteQuestion(@RequestParam("questionId")String id,
              @RequestParam("votedByUserId")String votedByUserId,@RequestParam("action")String action) throws JsonProcessingException, IOException, Throwable
{
     return objMapper.writeValueAsString(discussionService.updateVotesByQuestionId(id, votedByUserId, action));
}
```

also check that that `Map` returned by `discussionService.updateVotesByQuestionId(id, votedByUserId, action)` is not empty